# Emailing Medical Records Securely

Tags: encryption, email

Some doctors' offices give a personal email address, like Yahoo! or Gmail for patients to email medical records. What questions should I be asking them to make sure the email account is secure? Even if they supply an email address associated with their website, doesn't mean it's secure.

Comment: You don't transmit such information via email period. Email per definition is not a secure way of transmitting sensitive information.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox why is that?

Comment: @VipulNair Opportunistic encryption is better than nothing, but it's not going to stop an active attacker, and either way each mail server between you and the destination gets a plaintext copy. Sometimes this is good enough (gmail to gmail shouldn't be vulnerable to anyone outside Google for instance), but in general it is not.

Comment: @VipulNair There are too many dependencies, I will give a few examples. Even though the communication channel might (and I stress the might here) be encrypted the first thing that comes to mind is the type of encryption (some still use SSLv3). Second is who manages the server, e.g. how many people have access to this (these) server(s) because as AndrolGenhald mentioned, email is stored in plain text on the server. I always advice my client to avoid using email when PII needs to be transmitted.

Comment: In addition to my previous message, will the email be kept on the server or will the doctors actually download all their email in an email client (e.g. use POP3). How are the PC's in the doctor's office managed and who has access to these systems. How often do they update their machines in order to patch vulnerabilities. I have seen some still use Windows XP which is end of life like forever already.

Comment: I see.Thank u both @Jeroen-ITNerdbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against sending your medical records directly in an e-mail, although, this doesn't mean it isn't secure, but there is simply no way for you to know what sort of stuff is going on with that doctors email for sure.

You can use 2 channels for communication. On e-mail channel you provide your medical records in a AES256 encrypted zip file with a password. On the second channel, either that would be a paper note, sms, phone call you deliver the password for your encrypted files.

Comment: Wouldn't asymmetric encryption be used in this case instead of symmetric

Comment: @VipulNair In order to secure the email delivery process itself you could use PGP which would be a specific asymmetric encryption, but since we won't know if in this specific use case a doctor has a PGP setup it's not an option. For the zip file it's obviously symmetric, because your using a single key.

Comment: And then you'll have to trust the receptionist, or whomever, to handle the password securely; instead of just typing it into a new email (reply to email, address to self) and storing it alongside the encrypted one... But in principle this seems to be the best you can reasonably get. If your peer knows how to decrypt it.

Answer (score 3):

There are no questions you can ask to make sure it's secure, because it simply isn't. Email is often encrypted, but that's only part of the story. Due to the way email works, it may be encrypted between servers, but each server between you and the destination will have a plaintext copy (ie the encryption isn't end-to-end). Even worse, email encryption is almost always opportunistic, so if there is an active attacker they can downgrade it to plaintext.

Emailing medical information is generally a violation of HIPAA in the US, and probably other laws in different jurisdictions (an exception is emailing within a company or between companies that have a way to guarantee encryption is used between their servers).